# Put many things on one side of an inequality

Tags: notation

Is there notation for putting many variables on one side of an inequality?

Such as a, b, c, d > 0?

Comment: That looks ok to me

Comment: I'd say that's pretty standard. As long as you're not rolling over into multiple lines, I don't think any mathematician would have trouble interpreting your meaning.